# Proof diameter of a set equals diameter of its closure

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Is this a valid proof?

**Question :**

Show that $\mathrm{diam}(A)=\mathrm{diam}(\bar{A})$

**proof:**

$\forall \, x \in \bar{A},\forall\, \delta\,>0,\, B_\delta(x)\backslash x \, \cap A \neq \varnothing$. This implies $\forall x \in \bar{A},\, \exists \{x_n\}_0^\infty \in A :\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=x$

Let $\mathrm{diam}(\bar{A}) = \sup\{d(a,b):a,b\in \bar{A}\}$: 
then 
$$
\exists \{x_n\}_0^\infty, \{y_n\}_0^\infty : \lim_{n\to\infty}\{x_n\}=a, \quad \lim_{n\to \infty}\{y_n\}=b \text{ and } x_n,y_n\in A
$$
and thus, $d(\lim_{n\to \infty}\{x_n\},\lim_{n\to \infty}\{y_n\})=d(a,b)$. Since every $x\in A$ is also  in $\bar{A}$, 
$$
\mathrm{diam}(A)=\mathrm{diam}(\bar{A}).
$$

**Edit:** I want to know if a specific proof is valid, the proof I am asking about is not mentioned or discussed in the 3 year old link referenced as a duplicate by Yadati Kiran ([Confused about proof that diameter of a closure of a set is the same as the diameter of the set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1301507/confused-about-proof-that-diameter-of-a-closure-of-a-set-is-the-same-as-the-diam))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused about proof that diameter of a closure of a set is the same as the diameter of the set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1301507/confused-about-proof-that-diameter-of-a-closure-of-a-set-is-the-same-as-the-diam)

Comment: I'm asking if a specific proof is valid, the proof in question is not contained/discussed in the thread you linked to.

Comment: You say "let $diam(A) = \sup\{d(a,b):a,b\in \bar{A}\}$." Do you mean $A$ instead of $\bar{A}$? It's also a little weird that you're using the word "let" for a definition that is assumed in the question.

Comment: Thanks for finding that error. Also, in reference to using "let", I did it as an easy way to define $a$ and $b$. What would be a better way? Is there another faster way?

Comment: Oh, I see. That still sounds weird to me, but I'm no professional. 
More importantly, I feel that "since every $x \in A$ is also in $\bar{A}$" needs to be more justified because it's true that every $x \in \emptyset$ is in $\bar{A}$ but it's not generally true that $diam(\emptyset) = diam(\bar{A})$. Yes, you have elements in $A$ that are arbitrarily close to elements in $\bar{A}$ but I don't feel like you've made that explicit enough to be a proof.

Comment: The definition of $\bar{A}$ is that it is the minimum subset containing $A$. This implies $\forall x \in A x \in \bar{A}$. Should I add that to the proof?